# Collect tracking code implemented on the pages but data is not returned on the reporting tab in the web recommendation

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-analytics, einstein, einstein-recommendations

Good morning team!

I am assisting the customer in the implementation of the tracking collection code for travel data usage

according to him, the code has already been implemented in the pages but when accessing the reports tab no information is returned

what could be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you can quickly validate whether the script fires, by using the web developer tools in Chrome. After opening it, go to Network tab, and put igo in the search box. This will show you any calls being made to Collect Code/Marketing Cloud. See an example of this below:

[image]

If you do see requests going to *track_page_view* url as above, it means that the script is at least firing.

But... Does the client have a catalogue populated with all the relevant items which are being tracked? If the tracking script sends an ID in the `_etmc.push(["trackPageView", { "item" : "INSERT_ITEM" }]);`
call, which does not exist in the catalogue, this page view is not tracked.

Comment: Thanks for the answer lukas, by the way I'm using your contents from previous answers to help with this implementation.

The question would be the reporting tab, for it to be receiving the data is it also necessary for the catalog to be uploaded? I thought that this reporting would already capture the information only by the collect traking code and the catalog part would only be necessary if the information was sent to the DE IGO and PI

Comment: @petrick.hymans Yes, all this requires the catalogue to be connected and populated. Items not in the catalogue will throw an error in the collect code. But do keep in mind, collect code != analytics. You are much better off simply using GA or similar. Collect code is mainly for the Einstein recommendations, or to populate the IGO tables, as [described here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_pb_integration_with_contact_builder.htm&type=5)